# Refresh issue with WPF .NET 4.0 - Black Vertical lines

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0

I have an application that was original written in WPF targeting the 3.5 framework. We recently upgraded to target the 4.0 framework. Now when the user opens a window, most of the time, they get black vertical lines appearing in the window. The lines are in front of some controls and behind others. It is intermittent. It really seams like some kind of redraw issue as once they move the window a little, the lines go away. I can't find any reference to a bug like this anywhere and I am stumped as to what to try to get it resolved. The PC's that our users are running are quite powerful. They all have at least dual core processors, 8gig ram and solid state hard drives. We have also tried updating to the latest video drivers.

Any guidance would be helpful. Thanks.

[I don't have enough reputation to upload an image, so here is a link to one I saved online.](http://lantzr6.smugmug.com/Other/temp/image001/1240963248_ne3as-L.png)

Answer (score 2):

This looks very much like graphics driver issues.  I would recommend trying to disable hardware acceleration in the graphics and see if the issue goes away.  If so, report it as a bug to your graphics card vendor - hopefully a future driver will correct the issue.

Comment: We have tried to disable hardware acceleration, however apparently that is not an option on Windows 7.